# (fscanf(file, "%lf", &num) > 0) and segmentation fault in C

Tags: c, bind

I'm modifying a piece of the source code of bind, specifically the random order section of the rdataset.c file, which is below:

```
for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    dns_rdata_t rdata;
    isc_uint32_t val;

    isc_random_get(&val);
    choice = i + (val % (count - i));
    rdata = shuffled[i];
    shuffled[i] = shuffled[choice];
    shuffled[choice] = rdata;
    if (order != NULL)
        sorted[i].key = (*order)(&shuffled[i], order_arg);
    else
        sorted[i].key = 0; /* Unused */
    sorted[i].rdata = &shuffled[i];
}
```

I change the line with choice and let that variable be taken from a function like this

```
choice=weightCal();
```

and the code of function is

```
unsigned int weightCal() {
    FILE *file = fopen("weight.txt", "r");  
    double integers[10],prob[10]; 
    unsigned int i=0,j=0,k=0; 
    double sum=0,subSum=0,num; 
    unsigned int result=0;
    while(fscanf(file, "%lf", &num) > 0) {
        integers[i] =num;
        sum+=num;
        i++;    
    }
    rewind(file);    
    while(fscanf(file, "%lf", &num) > 0){
        subSum=subSum+num;  
        prob[j]= subSum / sum;  
        j++;
    }   
    srand(time(NULL));   
    double r = rand() / (double)RAND_MAX;    
    for(k=0;k<sizeof(prob)/sizeof(double);k++) {
        if (r <  prob[k]) {     
            result=k;       
            break;  
        }    
    } 
    fclose(file);
    return result;
}
```

then I recompile bind. The compilation works but when I use the command :

```
dig www.example.com. @127.0.0.1
```

it returns the error "Segmentation fault (core dumped)." I tried to debug it and the debugger told me that the error is in the line

```
while(fscanf(file, "%lf", &num) > 0)
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Your code has 2 different lines that are identical.... which one are you getting the error on??

Comment: the first one @abelenky

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the return value of this line:

```
FILE *file = fopen("weight.txt", "r");
```

I'd do it with:

```
FILE *file = fopen("weight.txt", "r"); 
if (file == NULL) 
{
    printf("Unable to open file weight.txt!  Theres the problem\n");
}
```

Comment: how can I get over this problem

Comment: Figure out WHY you cannot open weight.txt, and fix that.
It may be that the program is not running in the same directory as the text file.  It may be that the program does not have read-permissions to the file.

Answer (score 5):

Well, check that `file` is not `NULL` - that's a good starting point. A line like

```
while(fscanf(file, "%lf", &num) > 0)
```

will typically crash if there's something wrong with `file` (invalid pointer or damaged internal data structure). Although some platforms might potentially crash if the input value in the file is out of range for `double` type.

Also, depending on how local data is laid out on your platform, overwriting memory beyond the end of one of your arrays might destroy the value of `file`, turning it into an invalid pointer. You never check for an out-of-bound access in any of your cycles. Are you sure your input file has exactly 10 data values? (Note that the last cycle in your function can potentially iterate over exactly 10 elements, meaning that less than 10 will not do).

Comment: the file is not NULL.

Comment: How do you know that?  The code doesn't check it.  The program may not be running in the directory you think it is running in — it may have done `chdir("/")` or to some other directory, for example.  (And you have 5 minutes in which you can edit comments, so your two previous comments could easily be combined.)

Comment: What platforms would crash if the input value is out of range? Can you elaborate? That doesn't sound right.

Comment: @centosuser:  I can pretty much *promise* you that the `file`-variable **is** NULL.  All you're saying is that you believe the file exists.  But the program doesn't see it the same way.  The program may not have read-permissions to the file, or may be running in a different directory.  Whatever the reason, your program is failing because it cannot successfully `fopen` "weight.txt"

Comment: @John Kugelman: Overflow in `scanf` leads to undefined behavior, which can result in anything. I remember that I observed a crash caused by floating-point overflow on one of the versions of Sun Solaris with their native C compiler. It wasn't in `scanf` and it wasn't a "segmentation fault". But it was a crash triggered by overflow. I believe things like that can be controlled by platform-dependent FPU settings.

Comment: That is surprising news, indeed. I see that [overflow does lead to undefined behavior](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.std.c/03tnRCrdYOU), but I would never have thought that'd actually manifest as a crash! Color me amazed.

Comment: @John Kugelman: Well, if I remember correctly, in my case the program was crashing while attempting to convert a large `double` value to `unsigned int` type. So, it was a different situation. And again, it could have been caused by some specific FPU control setup.